# Why is localStorage getting cleared whenever I refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, use-effect, use-state

Like the title says, the localStorage I set registers the changes made to the `todoList` array and `JSON.stringify`s it; however, whenever I refresh the page the array returns to the default `[]` state.

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "task-list"

function TodoList() {
    const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const storedList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
        if (storedList) {
            setTodoList(storedList);
        }
    }, []);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todoList));
    }, [todoList]);
```

Comment: What does it say when you inspect your localStorage in your browser? ie going inspect > Application > Local Storage

Comment: wouldn't it better to do directly ```const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) || []);``` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you reload the app/component both effects will run, and React state updates are processed asynchronously, so it's picking up the empty array state persisted to localStorage before the state update is processed. Just read from localStorage directly when setting the initial `todoList` state value.

Example:

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "task-list"

function TodoList() {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState(() => {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) || []
  });
    
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todoList));
  }, [todoList]);

  ...
```

[image: Edit why-is-localstorage-getting-cleared-whenever-i-refresh-the-page]

Comment: This works, and is a method I learned in a react course, however the [react docs for `useState`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) indicate that the initializer function should be pure (only depends on its parameters and produces no side-effects). See my answer below for a method that does not violate this rule. [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73940073/1402511) for discussion on whether or not this requirement is important.

Answer (score 3):

The above solution does not work in all cases.  Instead add a conditional in front of the `localStorage.setItem` line in order to prevent the [] case.

```js
//does not work in all cases (such as localhost)
function TodoList() {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState(() => {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)) || []
  });
```

```js
//use conditional instead
 useEffect(() => {
    if (todoList.length > 0) {localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todoList))}
  }, [todoList])
```

Comment: this isn't great because an empty array is probably valid state e.g. once you remove all your todos

Answer (score 1):

Your React version is above v18 which implemented the <React.StrictMode>. If this is enabled in the index.js this code

```
useEffect(() => {
    const storedList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
    if (storedList) {
        setTodoList(storedList);
    }
}, []);
```

Won't work because it detects potential problems. If you removed <React.StrictMode> it will work but I won't recommend it. The best solution is the first two answers

Comment: no quite on the topic

Comment: worked for me since I am currently in development. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://typeofnan.dev/how-to-prevent-useeffect-from-running-on-mount-in-react/) demonstrates how to avoid running a `useEffect` hook on first render.

Here is your modified code that will not overwrite localStorage on the initial render:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "task-list"
const isMounted = useRef(false);

function TodoList() {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
    if (storedList) {
        setTodoList(storedList);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // don't store on initial render
    if (isMounted.current) {
      localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todoList));
    } else {
      isMounted.current = true;
    }
  }, [todoList]);
}
```

Comment: This also would work, but just FYI, the article you link is from 2021 and "isMounted" logic/checks have since become generally considered to be a bit of a React anti-pattern.

Comment: so, anti-pattern on the one hand, breaking a rule in the react docs on the other - is there another better way?

Comment: While I'm inclined to agree that, from a pure CS point, reading localStorage in the initializer function is *technically* impure, but also point out that in this case it's completely harmless. I think React applies the "pure function" label too rigidly. IMO the obvious intent there is that the initializer function should not be making *external* side-effects like fetching data or updating DBs, etc. Using a second effect to initialize the state and an "isMounted" variable are more moving parts and possibly gets weird with React 18's `StrictMode` double-mounting to ensure reusable state.

Comment: My understanding is that `StrictMode` is meant to catch side-effects and impure functions at development time by running things twice, but side-effects are expected in `useEffect` hooks so it shouldn't cause a problem to have an impure function there (that's their reason to exist). While having an impure function as an initializer doesn't cause a problem now, it could in the future (perhaps react will rely on the cached output of the initializer function at some point). Then again perhaps they'll just change the docs and soften the requirement!

Answer (score 0):

I am using RTK for a React project. My Redux store was cleared when I manually refresh pages. I found these 2 pages helpful to resolve the "Redux state not persisting" issues. [Persisting State Between Page Reloads in React](https://blog.bitsrc.io/5-methods-to-persisting-state-between-page-reloads-in-react-8fc9abd3fa2f) [RTK Store Setup](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#manual-store-setup)

Here is my store setup,

```js
## Store.ts file
import {combineReducers, configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import agentSlice from "../Reducers/agentSlice";

import operatorSlice from "../Reducers/operatorSlice";
import registrationSlice from "../Reducers/registrationSlice";
import driverSlice from '../Reducers/driver_Slice/driverSlice';
import configureAppStore_2 from './configureAppStore_2';



const saveToLocalStorage = (state:any) => {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state));
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
};

const loadFromLocalStorage = () => {
    try {
        const stateStr = localStorage.getItem('state');
        return stateStr ? JSON.parse(stateStr) : undefined;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return undefined;
    }
};


export const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
    agent: agentSlice,
    register: registrationSlice,
    operator:operatorSlice,
    driver:driverSlice,

});
const persistedStore = loadFromLocalStorage();

export const store =configureAppStore_2(persistedStore);


store.subscribe(() => {
    saveToLocalStorage(store.getState());
});


// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch


## configureAppStore_2.ts File:

import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {combinedReducer} from './store';


const configureAppStore_2=(preloadedState:any) =>{
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: combinedReducer,
    preloadedState,
  })

  //@ts-ignore
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && module.hot) {
    //@ts-ignore
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => store.replaceReducer(rootReducer))
  }

  return store
}

export default configureAppStore_2;
```

Answer (score -1):

To ensure that your data is not removed from local storage when you refresh the page, you can use the following code:

```
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "task-list"

function TodoList() {
    const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState(()=>{
    const storedList = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
    return storedList ? JSON.parse(storedList) : []
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todoList));
    }, [todoList]);
e
```