# useFetch custom hook doesn't trigger inner useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I'm trying to use a useFetch custom hook on a small todolist app that I'm working on to learn React.

I don't get why my useFetch function seems to work but its inner useEffect never triggers.

I tried removing the URL from dependencies array, adding the URL as an argument of the useEffect but nothing happened: my variable [response] stays null.

Here is the code for the useFetch :

utils.js:

```
export function useFetch(url) {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(url);
        if (url === undefined) return;

        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                const result = await getRequest(url);
                setResponse(result);
                setIsLoading(false);
            } catch (error) {
                setError(error);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [url]);

    return [response, setResponse, error, isLoading];
}
```

App.js:

```
import { useState, useMemo, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useFetch, postRequest, deleteRequest, getFormatedDate } from './utils';
//more imports

export default function App() {
    const [response] = useFetch('/items');
    const [titleValue, setTitleValue] = useState('');
    const [descriptionValue, setDescriptionValue] = useState('');
    const [deadlineValue, setDeadlineValue] = useState(new Date());
    const [doneFilter, setDoneFilter] = useState(0);
    const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState();
    const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(false);

    const onSave = useCallback(
        async () => {
            if (titleValue) {
                let valueToSave = {};
                valueToSave.title = titleValue;
                valueToSave.status = false;
                if (descriptionValue) valueToSave.description = descriptionValue;
                valueToSave.deadline = deadlineValue instanceof Date ?  deadlineValue : new Date();
                setData((prev) => [...prev, valueToSave]);
                setTitleValue('');
                setDescriptionValue('');
                setDeadlineValue(new Date());
                try {
                    await postRequest('add', valueToSave);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    throw err;
                }
            }
        },
        [descriptionValue, titleValue, deadlineValue]
    );

    const onDelete = useCallback(async (item) => {
        setData((items) => items.filter((i) => i !== item));
        try {
            await deleteRequest(item._id);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            throw err;
        }
    }, []);

    const onModif = useCallback(async (id, field) => {
        const res = await postRequest('update/' + id, field);
        if (res.ok) setShowDialog(false);
    }, []);

    const organizedData = useMemo(() => {
        if (!response) return;
        for (let d of response) d.formatedDeadline = getFormatedDate(d.deadline);
        response.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.deadline) - new Date(b.deadline));
        if (doneFilter === 1) return response.filter((e) => e.status);
        else if (doneFilter === 2) return response.filter((e) => !e.status);
        else return response;
    }, [response, doneFilter]);

    //more code

    return (
        // jsx
)}
```

console.logging works just above the useEffect but never inside.

Comment: Do you actually get any data from ```const result = await getRequest(url)```? It might help if you share the getRequest function.

Comment: The implementation of `useFetch` seems to work well. Do you get any errors?

Comment: The hook works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cvmfto?file=useFetch.ts Please provide a reproducible example. You can add to that example until you reproduce the error.

Comment: **NO**, the hook is broken in (current) React 18. There is no protection against setting state on an unmounted component and an error response never sets loading to false.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot easily recreate your issue but I can point out some issues with your `useFetch` hook -

```js
function useFetch(url) {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(url);
        if (url === undefined) return;

        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                const result = await getRequest(url);
                setResponse(result);
                setIsLoading(false);
            } catch (error) {
                setError(error);
                // ❌ loading == true
            }
        };
        fetchData();
        // ❌ what about effect cleanup?
    }, [url]);

    return [response, setResponse, error, isLoading]; // ❌ don't expose setResponse
}
```

Check out [Fetching Data](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#fetching-data) from the react docs. Here's the fixes -

```js
function useFetch(url) {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (url == null) return;
      let mounted = true                      // ✅ component is mounted

      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          if (mounted) setIsLoading(true);    // ✅ setState only if mounted
          const response = await getRequest(url);
          if (mounted) setResponse(response); // ✅ setState only if mounted
        } catch (error) {
          if (mounted) setError(error);       // ✅ setState only if mounted
        } finally {
          if (mounted) setIsLoading(false);   // ✅ setState only if mounted
        }
      };

      fetchData();

      return () => {
        mounted = false // ✅ component unmounted
      }
    },
    [url]
  );

  return { response, error, isLoading }
}
```

When you use it, you must check for `isLoading` first, then null-check the `error`. If neither, `response` is valid -

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const {response, error, isLoading} = useFetch("...")
  if (isLoading) return <Loading />
  if (error) return <Error error={error} />
  return (
    // response is valid here
  )
}
```

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75075651/633183) for a more useful `useAsync` hook.