# React useApi Hook results in endless loop when used in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created a react hook to perform api calls inspired by this [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/clean-api-call-with-react-hooks-3bd6438a375a).

The hook looks as followed:

```
function useApi<T>(apiFunc: (...args: Array<any>) => Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>) {
    const [data, setData] = useState<T | null>(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const controllerRef = useRef(new AbortController());

    const request = async (...args: Array<any>) => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await apiFunc(...args);
            setData(response.data);
        } catch (error: any) {
            setError(error.message || 'Unknown Error');
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return { request, cancel, data, error, loading };
};
```

Now I am using the hook in a component in the useEffect function:

```
const vacancyApi = useApi(getVacancy);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!!id) {
        vacancyApi.request(id);
    }
}, [id, vacancyApi]);
```

The problem is that when I add `vacancyApi` to the dependency array it results in an endless loop because vacancyApi is updated by the hook which then calls useEffect again.

I could just not add `vacancyApi` to the dependency array and it works but that seems ugly to me and not the right thing to do.

I also can't move the function out of the component because it's a hook and has to be created inside the component.

In the [articles](https://betterprogramming.pub/clean-api-call-with-react-hooks-3bd6438a375a) comments I read that it could be a solution to wrap the request function into a useCallback hook. But I haven't figured out how to do it properly, I still had the same problem.

```
const request = useCallback(async (...args: Array<any>) => {
    ...
}, [apiFunc]);
```

Is there a solution where I can call the api only if the id changes without removing the dependency of `vacancyApi` from the useEffect dependencies?

Comment: *"I could just not add vacancyApi to the dependency array and it works but that seems ugly to me and not the right thing to do."* Does it seem ugly and wrong not to put `setState` or values returned from `useRef` in the effect dependencies? What about out-of-scope constants?

Comment: Consider a more generic hook that decouples from axios and your API altogether. Does [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75075651/633183) help?

Comment: @Mulan If OP is using eslint with the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule, it will probably complain about the missing dependency, but not about `useState` setters that are omitted from the dependency array. I'm not sure how it detects the useState setters as being ok to omit, but that has been my experience.

Comment: I would add `(...args: Array<any>) => Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>` is a code smell that effectively deactivates TypeScript at the call site for the values returned by your hook.

Comment: @Mulan Yeah the typescript part is still work in progress :)

Comment: @JLRishe Yeah exactly I use Eslint but thats not the main reason, I read in an article that you should not remove dependencies from the array because of hidden rerenders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it now, your `useApi` hook is going to create a new `request` function every time it's called, so you need to put that in a `useCallback`:

```js
function useApi<T>(apiFunc: (...args: Array<any>) => Promise<AxiosResponse<T>>) {
    const [data, setData] = useState<T | null>(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const controllerRef = useRef(new AbortController());

    const request = useCallback(async (...args: Array<any>) => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await apiFunc(...args);
            setData(response.data);
        } catch (error: any) {
            setError(error.message || 'Unknown Error');
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }, [apiFunc]);

    return { request, cancel, data, error, loading };
};
```

In order this to work, this also requires that `apiFunc` is a constant value from one render to the next.

Once you've ensured that `request` isn't constantly changing, you need to use *that* in the dependency array for your `useEffect` not the whole object that `useApi` returns:

```js
const vacancyApi = useApi(getVacancy);

const { request: vacancyRequest } = vacancyApi;

useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
        vacancyRequest(id);
    }
}, [id, vacancyRequest]);
```

I believe that will do the trick.

Comment: eslint is complaining about the ```vacancyApi.request``` dependency too, it wants the vacancyApi as dependency. Why is that?

Comment: eslint can be a bit of a coconut head from time to time ^_^

Comment: @HansDabi Please see my edit. I think that will solve it.

Answer (score 2):

**no more `any`**

@JLRishe helps you solve your infinite loop but there's other issues with your code that are less straightforward. The biggest one being `(...args: Array<any>) => ...` effectively disabling TypeScript wherever this hook is used. Let's fix that using a more generic hook -

```js
// hooks.ts

import { DependencyList, useState, useEffect } from "react"

type UseAsyncHookState<T> = {
    loading: boolean,
    error: null  | Error,
    data: null | T
}

function useAsync<T>(func:() => Promise<T>, deps: DependencyList) {
  const [state, setState] = useState<UseAsyncHookState<T>>({ loading: true, error: null, data: null })
  useEffect(
    () => {
      let mounted = true
      func()
        .then(data => mounted && setState({ loading: false, error: null, data }))
        .catch(error => mounted && setState({ loading: false, error, data: null }))
      return () => { mounted = false }
    },
    deps,
  )
  return state
}

export { useAsync }
```

Why that `mounted` var? We need to make sure we don't attempt to set state on an unmounted component. See the React guide for [Fetching Data](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data).

Now separate axios logic from your components with a reusable `api` module -

```js
// api.js

import axios from "axios"

type User = {
  email: string,
  bio: string,
}

function getUser(id: number) {
  return axios.get<User>(`/users/${id}`)
}

// your other api functions ...

export { User, getUser, ... }
```

**Type-safety restored**. Now your components simply glue the pieces together without involving complex logic -

```js
// UserProfile.tsx

import { useAsync } from "./hooks"
import { getUser } from "./api"

function UserProfile(props: { userId: number }) {
  const user = useAsync(          // ✅ inferred type: AsyncHookState<User>
    () => getUser(props.userId),  // async call
    [props.userId],               // dependencies
  )
  if (user.loading)
    return <Loading />
  if (user.error)
    return <Error message={user.error.message} />
  if (user.data)
    return <UserData user={user.data} />
}
```

**no more nulls**

The `UseAsyncHookState` type has nullable fields which means we have to be mindful in the way we attempt to access the result. Always checking `loading` first, then for the presence of `error` before accessing `data`. We can take advantage of TypeScript 5's new [exhaustive switch..case completions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-beta/#exhaustive-switch-case-completions) by adjusting our hook's type -

```
type UseAsyncHookState<T> =
  | { kind: "loading" }
  | { kind: "error", error: Error }
  | { kind: "result", data: T }

function useAsync<T>(func:() => Promise<T>, deps: DependencyList) {
  const [state, setState] = useState<UseAsyncHookState<T>>({ kind: "loading" })
  useEffect(
    () => {
      let mounted = true
      func()
        .then(data => mounted && setState({ kind: "result", data }))
        .catch(error => mounted && setState({ kind: "error", error }))
      return () => { mounted = false }
    },
    deps,
  )
  return state
}
```

Now we can write these in *any* order without worry and TypeScript will warn us if we forget to handle all `kind`s -

```
function UserProfile(props: { userId: number }) {
  const user = useAsync(
    () => getUser(props.userId),  // async call
    [props.userId],               // dependencies
  )
  switch (user.kind) { // ✅ exhaustive switch..case
    case "loading":
      return <Loading />
    case "result":
      return <UserData user={user.data} />
    case "error":
      return <Error message={user.error.message} />
  }
}
```

**multiple uses of useAsync**

You can see a more complex use case where multiple `useAsync` calls are needed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75075651/633183).

Comment: Hmm that looks promising, will try