# How to call react custom hook that return a value inside useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that returns a value by parameters that it gets. I need to recreate this with any updated parameter so I need to do that inside useEffect but I can't call the hook inside useEffect. How could I implement it?

The custom hook:

`useApi.tsx`

```js
export default function useApi(id) {
  const api = useGlobalApi()
  const user = api.get(`..../${id}`)

  ...

  return user
}
```

`Api.tsx`

```js
export default function Api(id) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({})
  const data = useApi(id)

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = useApi(id)
    setUser(user)
  }, [id])



  ...
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app`

How can I resolve this and get the expected result?

Comment: does [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75594366/react-useapi-hook-results-in-endless-loop-when-used-in-useeffect/75594967#75594967) help you solve the problem?

Comment: Why are you recursively calling `useApi`?

Comment: updated, by mistake, theses are not the real components, just reflects the logic of my components that bigger and more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Return a memoized function (wrapped with `useCallback`) from the hook, and use that function in the `useEffect`.

Custom hook:

```
export default function useApi(id) {
  const api = useGlobalApi()
  
  return () => useCallback(() => api.get(`..../${id}`), [id])
}
```

Usage:

```
const getUser = useApi(id)

useEffect(() => {
  const callApi = async () => {
    const user = await getUser()
    setUser(user)
  }

  callApi()
}, [getUser])
```

You can also get an immutable function, and pass the `id` in the `useEffect`:

```
export default function useApi() {
  const api = useGlobalApi()
  
  return () => useCallback(id => api.get(`..../${id}`), [])
}
```

Usage:

```
const getUser = useApi()

useEffect(() => {
  const callApi = async () => {
    const user = await getUser(id)
    setUser(user)
  }

  callApi()
}, [getUser, id])
```

Comment: The `useApi` is a global component, I can't touch it, any idea? Does it make sense to create a wrap component for this use case and implement there the `useCallback`?

Comment: You don't change the original `useApi`. Just your custom hook.

Comment: The custom hook is global, too, and I don't want to touch it.

Comment: The dependency seems not correct in your usage, I need this to be updated by `id`, how can I recreate the response that I get from the `useApi` hook  by the id (in your answer the `getUser ` should be a value not a function that I can call it), I have to send the `id` every change.

Comment: A new `getUser` function is generated every time that a new `id` is passed.

Comment: Should I pass it here? `const user = await getUser()`

Comment: You pass it when you call `useApi(id) {`, and get a function with the `id` inside. When the `id` changes, the function would also change, and would trigger the `useEffect`.

Comment: See 2nd option for passing `id` to the function in `useEffect`.

Comment: First of all, thank you! second, I have tried it, I can't touch my custom hook - `useApi` hook so I can't insert into the `useCallback` only the api request as you suggested so I created a new wrapping custom hook that try to call the original custom hook inside a callback but I still get the same error, any idea? Thanks!

Comment: If you call a hook inside a custom hook, and then you call that custom hook inside `useEffect`, you'll get the same error message. In addition, see the new experimental `use` hook - https://vived.io/new-hook-is-coming-to-react-frontend-weekly-vol-109/.

Comment: > If you call a hook inside a custom hook, and then you call that custom hook inside useEffect, you'll get the same error message.

Correct, but the `useCallback` should not prevent this? this isn't the logic you suggested or if I implement it for the whole custom hook this should not work?

Comment: The solution is a function that is returned from the hook, to prevent the need of running a hook inside of `useEffect`, which is prohibited. The `useCallback` just prevents the function from being re-created unless it's deps changes.

Comment: so still not sure how does it solve my case...? can you kindly clarify?

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function useApi(id) {
    const [user,setUser]=useState(null)
    // maybe use a different name for useApi here, current hook name is `useApi` 
    // return value is usually set inside useEffect. 
    const api = useGlobalApi()

    useEffect(()=>{
  
    const userRes = api.get(`..../${id}`)
    setUser(userRes)
    },[])
    return user
  }
```

then inside `Api.tsx`

```
export default function Api(id) {
    const user=useApi()
    ...
  }
```

Comment: I can't insert the `useApi` component inside the `useEffect`, this is a big _global_ component that doing a lot of requests. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @ESI move it outside useEffect inside `useApid(di)`. you have two functions with same name

Comment: By mistake, updated, theses are not the real components, just reflects the logic of my components that bigger and more complicated.

Comment: @ESI the logic behind hooks is you use useState and useEffect the way how I constructred the `useApi`. if you followed the same in `useGlobalApi`, above code should work

Comment: I see that you combined the logic, you inserted the custom hook logic inside the component, I can't do that, I must to leave that separate so how I can call it every change if I can't do that in useEffect? any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: @ESI i did not use component. it is just a hook function. setting state inside `useEffect` with correct dependency array.

Comment: But it forces me to touch the custom hook, I want to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confused because you are using 2 hooks called 'useApi', but I'll try my best to help.

Since you are using a hook, you don't need to call is again on useEffect.

`Api.tsx`

```
export default function Api(id) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({})
  const usr = useApiCustom(id)

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(usr)
  }, [usr])

  ...
}
```

`useApiCustom.tsx`

```
export default function useApiCustom(id) {
  const api = useApi()
  const user = api.get(`..../${id}`)

  return user
}
```

Comment: updated, by mistake, theses are not the real components, just reflects the logic of my components that bigger and more complicated.

Comment: Did try my answer? Is it working?

Comment: By your answer I saw that my example doesn't exactly match my use case, posted a new question with more specific example, can you kindly take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75781017/13029900)? Thanks!