# How to call custom hook that return a value inside useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that return an object by parameter that it gets, I need to recreate this with any updated parameter so I need to do that inside `useEffect` but I can't call the hook inside useEffect. Any idea how to implement it?

The custom hook:

`useBuilder.tsx`

```js
export default function useBuilder(user) {
  const api = useGlobalApi()
  const user = ...

 // doing a lot of requests and logic here that depends on the current user

  ...

  return builder
}
```

For each selected user I need a new `builder` object constructed and returned from the custom hook depends on the selected user.

The usage:

`Api.tsx`

```js
export default function User() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const [user, setUser] = useState({})
  const [builder, setBuilder] = useState({})

  const usersData = api.get('/../users')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!usersData?.length) return
    setUsers(usersData)
    setUser(usersData[0])
  }, [usersData])

  useEffect(() => {
    const builder = useBuilder(user)
    setBuilder(builder)
  }, [user])

  return (
    <Select
      value={user}
      onChange={e => {
        setUser(user)
      }}
    >
      {users.map(user => (
        <MenuItem key={user.id} value={user}>
          {user.name}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  )
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app`

Any idea how can I resolve this and get the expected result?

**Edit:**

I want to avoid touching the custom hook since this is a global custom hook with a lot of usages.

Comment: What happens when you don't break the rules of hooks (useBuilder outside useEffect)?

Comment: Where can I put it if I need a new `builder` with any selected user?

Comment: Hooks are not insatiable objects, they are pure functions that follow the rules of hooks, therefore, your premise is fundamentally React non-conforming. I suggest reading about [thinking in React](https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react). Furthermore I believe your problem is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) meaning you are trying to get help with your attempted solution rather than the actual problem.

Comment: I'd like to hear about A solution that would prevent this problem, even if it wouldn't be a fix to my code, but another approach that I couldn't get to.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the effect where you call `useBuilder`, just call the custom hook at the top level of your component. However, the custom hook will be called when either the `users` or `user` state variable changes, but you should still get the result that you want since `useBuilder` does its logic based only on the `user`.

```
export default function User() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const [user, setUser] = useState({})
  // const [builder, setBuilder] = useState({}) // remove this
  const builder = useBuilder(user) // use custom hook here

  const usersData = api.get('/../users')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!usersData?.length) return
    setUsers(usersData)
    setUser(usersData[0])
  }, [usersData])

  return (
    <Select
      value={user}
      onChange={e => {
        setUser(user)
      }}
    >
      {users.map(user => (
        <MenuItem key={user.id} value={user}>
          {user.name}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  )
}
```

Comment: I want avoid touching the custom hook, this is a global custom hook with a lot of usages, any idea how can I deal that without changes inside the custom hook? Thanks!

Comment: It is possible but not ideal for this specific case.

Comment: Just modified the answer. Also, it would be helpful to add that you can't change the custom hook to the question that way others can provide their solutions with that in mind.

Comment: It seems to work but I don't want it to update for every render as this operation takes a lot of time so I want to avoid unnecessary re-creations, what do you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the best approach if we're not able to modify the custom hook. Also, I don't think you have to worry because when the `users` state variable changes, the `user` state variable will also change. You only have to have that in mind if you add another state variable not related to the users.

Comment: I have other states not related to users in that component...

Comment: then modifying the custom hook or creating a new one would be the solution

Comment: Does duplicating a complicated and large custom hook make sense?

Comment: As long as you get the result you need, it could make sense

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function component that returns the custom hook. The use... prefix only obeys the hook rules when in a function.
Read the docs:[react docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

Comment: Can you kindly clarify? What is the code that should extract to a function component?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer and add all relevant details from the link. And example of a functional component should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function customBuilder(){
  function useBuilder(user) {
  const api = useGlobalApi()
  const user = ...

 // doing a lot of requests and logic here that depends on the current user

  ...

  return builder
}

return useBuilder;

}
```

Comment: Did you notice to my edit? I want to avoid touching the custom hook since this is a global custom hook with a lot of usages. Thanks!